# Access static content of extjs production build in Django static path

Tags: django, extjs

I am facing problem with static content such as .png, .jpg files in Django+extjs environment.

I develop my client side in Extjs with sencha environment and test it locally with sencha server (`sencha app watch`) which works fine and I see the static images on the UI page.

Now I take a production build of that app (`sencha app build classic`).

It generates two folders.

1. Classic   : This has app.js and CSS,fonts etc...
2. resources : (Here is the problem) This has static files like images and json files(if any)

Now I copy these two folders to my Django static path and access the app.js and and CSS files from Django's HTML template. This works.

However, The problem is Django is unable to locate the image files that are there in resources folder (mentioned in list item 2).

If the URL is 'localhost:81/app_name', it searches for the images in the below path 
`localhost:81/app_name/resources/images/abc.png`

But is should look in the below path to get these files
`localhost:81/static/resources/images/abc.png`

What am i missing here? How Do I tell Django/Extjs to search for the static content in `localhost:81/static/resources/images/abc.png`

Please suggest.

Comment: what is your STATIC_URL set to in your settings.py file?

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
    STATIC_PATH=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
   STATIC_MYDASHBOARD=os.path.join(STATIC_PATH, 'mydashboard','resources','images')
   STATICFILES_DIRS=(
    STATIC_PATH,
    STATIC_MYDASHBOARD
)

This is the static related code in settings.py